# Creating Library .m File in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

So I have a generic question.  I have a bunch of functions, some of which are void, some which return NSString*, some which return NSDictionary*, etc.  I use these functions in a bunch of different classes.  I want to just create a library .m file that I can include in the classes that use them, so I don't have to copy and paste these functions all over the place.  I'm pretty sure this shouldn't be hard to do but I can't seem to get this to work for anything but void functions.

Example:

```
//Library.h
(NSString*)doStuff{
    NSString* test = "hello world";
    return test;
}

(void)print{
    NSLog(@"Hi");
}
```

I wish to basically have 1 file that I can just use an import statement on, but am uncertain if this is possible in obj c.

Robin

Comment: You need to be more specific than "can't get this to work"...or prepare for rants.

Comment: I am not sure what you are having problems with it but whenever I have to write some code that I want to share only the method declarations and not the code, I create static libraries for it. Here is a [link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/) for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the plain old C style:

```
// ======== yourlib.h =========
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NSString *doStuff();
void print();


//======== yourlib.m =========
#import "yourlib.h"
NSString *doStuff(){
    NSString *test = @"hello world";
    return test;
}

void print(){
    NSLog(@"Hi");
}
```

Or, you can use the category feature to attach to existing frameworks:

```
// ======= youlib.h ========
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSString (YourCategory)
+ (NSString *)someStringFromString:(NSString*)string;
- (NSDictionary *)someDictionaryFromString;
@end
// ======= yourlib.m =======
#import "yourlib.h"
@implementation NSString(YourCategory)
+ (NSString *)someStringFromString:(NSString*)string {
   ...
   return aString;
}
- (NSDictionary *)someDictionaryFromString {
   ...
   return aDict;
}
@end
```

Comment: thanks.  was trying the C way but just had some errors in my syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use class methods. Write your all common functions in `Library` class.

```
  //Library.m

+(NSString*)doStuff{
    NSString* test = "hello world";
    return test;
}

+(void)print{
    NSLog(@"Hi");
}


#import "Library.h"
@implementation ClassA

-(void)MethodA
{
 [Library doStuff];
 [Library print];
}
```